# How to match a sequence of characters that doesn't form a specific word?

Tags: regex, vim

This may not be possible with regular expressions, and if not, please explain why, or provide a link.

Ultimately, I'm trying to modify my php syntax file for vim to fix a glitch when `/* */` comments contain doc tags (e.g. `/** @param value description */`).  I prefer to keep the highlighting even though the doc tags are benign inside `/* */`.

Currently, one `syn match` for phpDocTags eats the end-of-comment token (*/).

```
# vim syntax line
syn match phpDocTags "@\(var\)\s\+\S\+.*" containedin=phpComment

# example php code
/* @var $something 12 34*/

# vim regex match
@var $something 12 34*/
```

**I want to replace the `.*` in the phpDocTags regex with an expression that says, "Match any character that does not form `*/`", or alternately, "Match any character that is not a `*` followed by `/`."**

Currently I have a partial solution using negative lookahead, however, it suffers from the issue that it doesn't match the character before the `*/`.  This works well enough if a space always precedes the `*/`.

```
# vim syntax line v2
syn match phpDocTags "@\(vars\)\s\+\S\+\(.\(\*/\)\@!\)*" containedin=phpComment

# same example php code

# vim regex match v2
@var $something 12 3
```

So with version 2, the new expression says, "Match any character that does not precede `*/`."

Keep in mind that the `*/` may be on a different line, so it must be considered optional.  Here's brief list of inputs to test against.

```
INPUT                                 EXPECTED MATCH
/* @var $something 1234*/             @var $something 1234
/* @var */                            @var      # but prefer no match if possible
/* @var $something 1234               @var $something 1234
/* @var $something 1 / 2 * 34*/       @var $something 1 / 2 * 34
```

P.S.  If there's a flag I can add to phpComment that withholds the `*/` from contained expressions, please mention that in the comments.  The primary focus of this question is regular expressions, not vim's syntax framework.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you can make use of it but `.*[^\*/]` matches everything (greedily) that's before a `*/`. `@var.*[^\*/]` seems to work with my limited tests.

Comment: good point.  I forgot to mention in my question that the `*/` is optional, so there's no guarantee that it will always be there.  Updated question with more examples.

Comment: [Please see this screenshot.](http://i.imgur.com/0pzHTIG.png)

Comment: [And this one.](http://i.imgur.com/ZKWqrVV.png)

Comment: @romainl I think you don't need to escape the `*` between brackets. Also, it should be specified that your solution doesn't work is there is anything _after_ the `*/`.

Comment: did you don't want to match the text inside comment line if it contains `$`?

Comment: @Qeole, you are right about the escaping and yes, my proposed solution doesn't work if there's anything after the `*/` but I tried to stick with the OP's requirrements.

Comment: @romainl No problem about that, I just thought it was worth mentioning. Your proposed answer is nice, by the way, and I gave an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@var\s*\S.*\ze\*/
```

does what you ask while still conforming to @Qeole's additional "if there is anything after the `*/`" requirement.

`\ze` is a convenient way to mark the end of the actual match while still providing the regular expression engine with relevant rules.

[image: @var\s*\S.*\ze*/]

Comment: It is worth noting that this answer still eats the `*/` when used in the `syn match` expression, but it still answers the question since regex is the focus of inquiry, not vim's syntax framework.  Well done, romainl.

Answer (score -1):

This regex matches your target:

```
(?<=\/\* )@var [^*].*?(?=\*\/|$)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/bmw97JoTI5) tested against your sample input.

It also doesn't match the empty comment as you hoped.

It works using:

- A look behind to set the start of capture
- a reluctant quantifier, in case further comments follow on the same line (see example  in demo link)
- an alternate (either end of comment or end of line) look ahead to set the end of capture

Look aheads don't capture anything, so the entire match (not a group) is your target input.

Comment: Yes, this is a regex question but Vim has its own regex syntax.